# Implementation of knockout dynamic add row

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have come across this code for creating a new Employee using knockout js and I am hoping for some assitance in attempting to understand it?

mvcModel variable created - `var mvcModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(mvcModel, {
    'AdditionalEmployees': {
        create: function(options) { return createAdditionalEmployee(options.data); }
    }
  });
```

So in the MVC model there is a `List<AdditionalEmployee> AdditionalEmployees` and AdditionalEmployee is a class with FirstName/Surname/Salary. So is the above saying map any AdditionalEmployees to the createAdditionalEmployee function - so if there were 3 AdditionalEmployees saved in the DB this function would run 3 times when the page loads to create those 3 rows?

I am also wondering what the options is that is passed to function and then what is options.data?

Finally then the createAdditionalEmployee function is below:

```
  var createAdditionalEmployee = function (data) {
        if (data) {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        } else {
            return {
                Id: ko.observable(),
                FirstName: ko.observable(),
                Surname: ko.observable(),
                Salary: ko.observable()
            };
        }
    };
```

Again I am wondering is that data the item in the List that may be passed - and the differences between returning ko.mapping.fromJS(data) and return ko.observable() for each field which is what gets hit I assume if the user from screen clicks the button to add the new Employee row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mapping.fromJS()` function automatically creates observable lists and properties when given a model. From the snippet you are providing, the developer decided to customise the creation of each of the elements in the `AdditionalEmployees` list in his/her model.

The function `createAdditionalEmployee()` will be called for each item in the list - so you are correct, if there's 3 items in the list, then that function will be called 3 times. In this scenario, the `data` parameter will NOT be null, so new objects will be created again using the `mapping.fromJS()` function.

Without seeing the whole example, I suspect you are also correct in saying that the `createAdditionalFunction()` function will be also used when the user (assumedly) presses an "Add" button on the screen to create a new employee, but in this case with NULL as the `data` parameter.

You can find more details about the mapping plugin `fromJS()` function and customising it in the KnockoutJS [documentation page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).